# Filtering over a list of date ranges in one ORM call

Tags: django, django-models

I am having the following structure:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=80)   

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Attempts(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey("Player")
    game = models.ForeignKey("Game")
    won = models.BooleanField()
```

The class Attempts logs the attempts of each player and whether he has won or lost a game.Now I want to get number of people attempting a particular game in agr groups.For example people aged 0-18 have attempted a game 5 times and so on.I have consulted the following this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Ngex2o4Lz1g) in django users and made the following code:

```
ranges = [(0,18),(18,25),(25,50)]
now = datetime.now()

groups = {}
for (a,b) in ranges:
    # print str(a) + " " +str(b)
    newer_date = (now - relativedelta(years=a)).date()
    older_date = (now - relativedelta(years=b)).date()
    print str(newer_date)
    print str(older_date)

groups[str(a)+","+str(b)] = Attempts.objects.filter(game__pk = "101",player__dob__range=(older_date,newer_date)).count()
```

This also gives result correctly as:

```
{"0,18": 2, "25,50": 1, "18,25": 1}
```

How ever the queries made by this code are  equal to number of categories in the ranges.I want to some how get this data in one single ORM query.Is it possible to do so ?